# Sort cursor according to Date Time

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-contentprovider

I have a cursor that fetches some data from my SQLite database via a Content Provider.

I want to sort the rows according to date, which I tried by using:

```
FeedTables.PostTable.COLUMN_PUBLISHED + " ASC"
```

Problem is, this only sorts it by day, not the date. So a "newer" row might be last, while a "old" row is at the top.

Example of a date in the database:

```
Fri, 16 Oct 2015 19:38:20 +0100
```

The COLUMN_PUBLISHED is of the type Date Time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can control the format of your date in sqlite database, you should save it in long time,like what `System.currentTimeMillis()` get,it's more effective and reasonable.
If you can't,then you should define a algorithm to compare your date of that format.

Comment: Ok, I will try that, hoped that there was something already built in that could help me, but guess this is the only way. Thanks.